# VBA delete row deletes everything in worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

The code below deletes everything in the worksheet, even if the value is in the named range. The column it needs to check is column I on sheet1 and the range is in A1:A45 on sheet2:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    'Deletes rows where one cell does not meet criteria
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        Dim criteria As String
        Dim found As Range
        Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i =212 to 2 step -1

       criteria = ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value

       With ws2.Range("A1:A45")
           Set found = .Find(What:=criteria, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
       End With

        If found Is Nothing Then
            ws1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `criteria = ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value` you are checking first column, not `I`. To check `I` column please try `criteria = ws1.Cells(i, 9).Value` or `criteria = ws1.Cells(i, "I").Value`

Comment: Try stepping through your code in debug mode and watching how your variables evolve ([instructions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)). If that doesn't help, then I suggest you see this for guidance: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In the "never hurts to check the obvious" category: Are you certain that there's at least one item on Sheet1 that exists on Sheet2, and, therefore, shouldn't be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

`ws1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete` could just be `ws1.Rows(i).Delete`.  I would step through with F8 in Visual Basic to see what it's actually doing.

Answer (score -1):

Your macro would live anything in the range ONLY if that row would contain text from ALL 200+ rows of sheet 1.

You should have your outer `for` cycling through rows of sheet 2 and delete it only of that doesn't contain any of the values from sheet 1.